# How do I add an input to a WooCommerce product so it can be grabbed on payment?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks, hook-woocommerce

Have a site that's WooCommerce.

It has an input field for name. When the user input their name and buys the product for engraving I want the name to come along after payment processing so I can get it. This isn't a product page deal, there's only a front page with text input and select a product.

Let me know if you have an questions as this is my first post, I may not be clear.

Comment: [Product Add Ons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/)

Comment: @helgatheviking thanks. I was trying to learn how to do it through the code though.